# Nested query using with?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I wish to get all roles with users, but I want to specify the user.

It's a many to many relationship.

```
Role::with('users')->get();
```

The above gets all roles with their users, I wish to get all roles and only display a specific user next to the ones they exist in. I still want roles in which they don't exist in.

I think I need to use a nested query but cant quite get the syntax correct using 'with'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the users inside the "with", like this:

```
Role::with(array('users' => function($query) use ($username) {
    $query->where('user_name', '=', $username);
}));
```